# insert a PHP page output into a jquery varible

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string, variables

I've created a PHP page that outputs a string variable from my database (this string simulate a multidimensional array) , I want to use this string as a variable in a jquery code (external JavaScript file).
the problem that its not working.

I've tried:

```
var data = [$.get( "string.php" );];
```

how can i insert a PHP page output into a jquery variable ?

Comment: With an Ajax call. PhP don't work as Javascript works.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want something like this:

```
$.get( "string.php", function(response){
    var data = response;
});
```

Seeing from your comment that you are expecting to get an Array as a response. You need to parse that.
I suggest you make your response into a JSON object (this makes parsing a lot easier).
Than you could just do :

```
var data = $.parseJSON(response);
```

And you will get an Array with objects.

To make your response JSON you could use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) to encode your Array.

Comment: its still not working. maybe i'll explain it more specific: i have this variable in jquery : var data = [{address:'sweden vaxjo' ,title:'test',description:'hi',area:'Kronoberg',category:'Activities',frequency:'One time',when:'17:00'},{address:'sweden kalmar' ,title:'hi',description:'hi',area:'Kalmar',category:'Activities',frequency:'One time',when:'hh'}];.... now the PHP page gives the same output = so how can i put this output in my script?

Comment: Looks like JSON. You want it to be an Array?

Comment: iv'e already build this Array manually (as a string) in my PHP page...

Comment: @user2828251 You should use [json_encode](http://uk3.php.net/json_encode) instead of writing it yourself.